# Erro em SendMessageToWinControl - A control type was not specified

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Tenho uma aplicação na web que gera etiqueta de código de barras.
Para que um client consiga imprimir, preciso acessar a porta **COM** do computador.

Criei um projeto que faz essa função. Mas para que a etiqueta seja impressa, preciso que minha aplicação passe os parâmetros para o novo projeto.

Quando vou executar a função que deveria fazer isso, aparece um erro: **`0x800a01b6 - Erro em tempo de execução do JavaScript: O objeto não dá suporte para a propriedade ou método: SendMessage()`**.

Notei também que o controle que criei não está funcionando direito, como segue na imagem abaixo:

[image: Imagem do erro]

Já tentei de tudo, mas não consigo fazer funcionar. Acredito que se o erro da imagem sumir, eu possa fazer funcionar.

Segue abaixo o código que envia os dados para o projeto e o código que recebe os dados.

**Envia os dados**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Impressão de Etiqueta</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    function SendMessageToWinControl() 
    {                      
        var winCtrl = document.getElementById("PrintBarcode");

        winCtrl.SendMessage(document.form1.HiddenField1.value,
                        document.form1.HiddenField2.value,
                        document.form1.HiddenField3.value,
                        document.form1.HiddenField4.value,
                        document.form1.HiddenField5.value);       
    }        
    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload = "SendMessageToWinControl()" >
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <object id="PrintBarcode"
                classid="http:codbarra.dll#codbarra.UserControl1"
                name="PrintBarcode" height="150" width="360" VIEWASTEXT>        
            </object>

            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField3" runat="server" />        
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField4" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField5" runat="server" />
         </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Recebe os dados**

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SendMessage(string paciente, string nome, string amostra, string cliente, string pedido)
    {
        c19tbl20.Text = cliente;
        c1tbl374.Text = pedido;
        c2tbl375.Text = amostra;
        c1tbl372.Text = paciente;
        c2tbl372.Text = nome;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta colocando o HTML inteiro? Pode ser um problema de declaração de tags.

Comment: Como eu faço isso Cigano? Sou novo aqui e não estou conseguindo postar o código todo.

Comment: Clique em editar, logo abaixo da pergunta.

Comment: Pronto Cigano, coloquei todo o código HTML da página.

Answer (score 0):

O atributo `onload` dentro de `<body>` está com o uso sendo cada vez mais desencorajado. O uso atualizado ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Impressão de Etiqueta</title>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        window.onload = function() {
            var winCtrl = document.getElementById("PrintBarcode");

            winCtrl.SendMessage(document.form1.HiddenField1.value,
                            document.form1.HiddenField2.value,
                            document.form1.HiddenField3.value,
                            document.form1.HiddenField4.value,
                            document.form1.HiddenField5.value);
        }

    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Certo Cigano, porém não é esse o problema que estou tendo.
Tenho essa mesma Thread em outro fórum. Veja aqui: 
http://forums.asp.net/p/1987478/5700180.aspx?Re+Error+in+SendMessageToWinControl+A+control+type+was+not+specified
É um problema que nunca tive antes. Está muito difícil de se resolver.